# ndnSIM : content store

Tags: c++, ns-3, ndnsim

which method to add data in content store in  forwarding strategy ndnSIM ?
i have tried to use  `cs::Cs::insert(data);` `after beforeSatisfiedInterest` unfortunately I have no result

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually manually add data on the default NDNsim. The content store is setup to only accept data that satisfies an interest in the "Pending Interest Table".

For manually entering data to a CS, you'd need to make changes to NDNsim with something like [this](https://www.lists.cs.ucla.edu/pipermail/ndnsim/2017-May/003713.html) discussed on the mailing list.